# Can you use normal correlation for vectors with only 2 (or 3), ordered, levels?

Tags: r, correlation, association-measure, ordinal-data

When one wants to compute the correlation of two vectors of a continues variables, one uses pearson (or spearman) correlation.

**But what should (can) one use for the case of two vectors with 2 (or 3) ordered levels only?  Is spearman enough, or does it require another method?**

I remember coming across someone who once claimed to me that OR (odds ratio) is more fitting for such situations (for 2 by 2 tables, where order has no meaning), is this true?

Here is an example R code, for allowing of answers relating to the same example:

```
set.seed(10)

x2 <- sample(c(-1,1),50, T)
x3 <- sample(c(-1:1),50, T)
y3 <- sample(c(-1:1),50, T)
y2 <- sample(c(-1,1),50, T)

cor(x3,y3, method = c("spearman"))
cor(x2,y2, method = c("spearman"))
cor(x3,y2, method = c("spearman"))
```

p.s: for the 2 by 2 case, I followed from the comments that categorical "measures of association" is the term to look for.  However, Part of the time I am comparing 2 on 3 tables, where on the factor with 3 levels there is order - so I would like to take use of that information.

Comment: In the context of categorical variables, one usually talks of a "measure of association" instead of "correlation". Searching for this term should lead you to lots of options.

Comment: Thanks Aniko. I'll correct my question here (and also look for it)

Comment: After a second thought - what I am looking at here is ordered, so looking at three levels as categorical would not fit here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- There are many different binary-binary and ordinal-ordinal measures of association.
  SPSS provides names and algorithms for many of them under [proximities](ftp://ftp.spss.com/pub/spss/statistics/spss/algorithms/proximit.pdf)
  and [crosstabs](http://support.spss.com/productsext/spss/documentation/statistics/algorithms/14.0/crosstabs.pdf).
- I'm also intrigued by  [tetrachoric](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/09/tetrachoric-correlations-overview-and.html) (binary-binary) and [polychoric](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/tetra.htm) (ordinal-ordinal) correlations that
  aim to estimate the correlation between theorised latent continuous variables.
- You can use Pearson's correlation. However, it is not always the most meaningful metric of association. Also, confidence intervals and p-values that assume continuous normal variables wont be perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than two levels, you can use (M)CA:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis

Answer (score 2):

The OR is a good measure of association, but sometimes people prefer a correlation coefficient for interpretation because it has a [-1, 1] scale.

For binary variables, the Phi statistic provides Pearson's correlation (see Jeromy's comment).  Cramer's V is applicable when you have more than 2x2 cases.  For details, see the following references:

- [Effect size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size)
- [Correlation](http://faculty.chass.ncsu.edu/garson/PA765/correl.htm)
- [Cramer's V](http://edpsych.ed.sc.edu/seaman/edrm711/questions/categorical.htm)

I've never used any of these, so hopefully someone will jump in and say if there are good reasons for preferring them.

Comment: Quick note: Phi and Pearson correlation give the same value. Phi is just a simpler calculation procedure.

Comment: And Cramer's V gives the same value as Phi for 2x2 tables.