# Relationship between categorical variable (depression) and a continuous variable

Tags: self-study, ordinal-data, association-measure

I appreciate this question is quite simple to ask but I want to make sure I direct myself in the right direction.

I want to test the association between a continuous variable (BMI) and a categorical (depression). Since Pearson's correlation is for continuous variables, which test would be appropriate?

Comment: Is the depression variable categorical or is it ordinal?

Comment: it is ordinal. Do you have an idea what test I can use to correlate both variables?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103253/non-parametric-measure-of-strength-of-association-between-an-ordinal-and-a-conti, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/measure-of-association-between-non-dichotomous-ordinal-variable-and-continuous-v, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/can-you-use-normal-correlation-for-vectors-with-only-2-or-3-ordered-levels/1981#1981